# Import error with win32com.gen_py

Tags: python, win32com

I'm developing a Python application that can interface with Outlook and send emails on Outlook's behalf. Because of this, I need the use of the `win32com` library, in order to use `win32com.client`. 
In addition to this, the same Python script will also have to access a MySQL database using the Oracle mysql-connector. Because of this, Python34 must be used as this is the only version I managed to get working with the sql-connector. 
Now here comes the crux of the issue. I have installed win32com (as it is not pre-installed with Python34) and it installed with no errors, and I can import win32com fine within python. However, when importing win32com.client, it gives the below error message:

```
>>> import win32com.client
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 60, in __init__
        _LoadDicts()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 110, in _LoadDicts
        f = open(os.path.join(win32com.__gen_path__, "dicts.dat"), "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\dicts.dat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 143, in GetGeneratePath
        os.stat(fname)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\__init__.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from . import gencache
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 666, in <module>
        __init__()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 62, in __init__
        Rebuild()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 653, in Rebuild
        _SaveDicts()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 69, in _SaveDicts
        f = open(os.path.join(GetGeneratePath(), "dicts.dat"), "wb")
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 145, in GetGeneratePath
        f = open(fname,"w")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\__init__.py'
```

Beautiful error, isn't it! I checked the directory `'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\'` manually to see what is there, and here's the thing, it's completely empty. When I installed `win32com` I installed with administrator permissions, so that couldn't have been the issue. I have also re-installed the `win32com` module to see if that might've fixed it but to no avail.
If anybody with a bit more experience with Python could offer some advice on what I need to install or repair I would be appreciative

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue here. Turns out I need to run Python as Administrator, should have worked that out given the Permission error. Strange how the gen_py directory is still empty, however.

Comment: When running as a different user, python probably searches for modules in an entirely different location.

Comment: Always running Python as administrator is not really a solution. Neither do I think that `pywin32` has such a blatant design flaw. Must be something else - maybe one needs to run it as admin one time (that would still be a bug, though not a critical one).

Comment: @DanielleM. probably has the right idea. In order to install the win32com module, I had to use administrator mode, due to system restrictions. Due to this it could have quite possibly installed in an entirely different directory, but even still this is quite an odd bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and reinstalled AS ADMINISTRATOR the pywin32-XXX.exe installer for the win32com.client module, and everything works fine now.
Good luck.